# Java Thread Creates extra Threads for unclear reasons

Tags: java, multithreading

Java Thread Creates extra Threads I'm not sure why this happens! I'm still a noob at java if its very obvious I'm sorry but please help me out

Well I created 2 threads to do something but there are extra threads created

here's the code

```
import java.util.*;    
import java.util.Arrays;

class consuming_producing extends Thread {
   static int arrX[] = new int[300];
    int y;
    static int var=0;

    int Request_type;

    consuming_producing(int x, int Request) {
        y = x;
        Request_type = Request;

    }
    int thread_number;
    consuming_producing(int x, int Request ,int thread) {
        y = x;
        thread_number=thread;
        Request_type = Request;

    }



    public synchronized void run() {

        switch (Request_type) {
            case 1: {                                                  
            // start producing the data and store it to the array
                for (int i = y; i < 300; i = i + 3) {
                    arrX[i] = (int) (Math.random() * 10 + 1);
                    System.out.println("produced " + arrX[i]);
                }
            }

            // *******************
            case 2: {                  // consuming the data
                for (int ww = y; ww < y+150;ww++) {
                    int sum = Arrays.stream(arrX).sum();
                    System.out.println("Sum  =" +var+" by thread " + thread_number);
                    //Arrays.fill(arrX,0);
                    var+=1;
                }
            }    
        }
    }
}
```

```
class consumer_producer {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        consuming_producing arr_Producer_obj[] = new consuming_producing[3];   
          // create a [enter image description here][1]thread for producing
        for (int i=0;i<3;i++){
            int x  =0;
            arr_Producer_obj[i]=new consuming_producing(x,1);
            arr_Producer_obj[i].start();
            x+=1;
        }

        // ***************
        consuming_producing arr_Consumer_obj[]=new consuming_producing[2];
        int thread=1;  // this is the name of thread im creating for ny refrence
        int x=0;
        for (int i=0;i<=1;i++){
            arr_Consumer_obj[i]=new consuming_producing(x,2,  thread);
            arr_Consumer_obj[i].start();
            x+=150;
            thread+=1;**
        }
    }
}
```

here's the image of output please check this

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xRlLp.png]

Comment: figured it out it was just that i forgot to add Break; after the switch statement and so the thread ran the rest of the code as well adding the break fixed it.  thank you

Answer (score 0):

each time your program reaches a Thread.start() method, its creating a new thread, plus the base thread of the main() method/entry point.
Your main method has 2 for loops, the first looks like it would create 3 threads, and the 2nd looks like it would create 2 additional threads.

When you extend the Thread class, and implement the 'run()' method, calling start() on the instance of the class will create a new thread to run the 'run()' method on.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I understood how the thread works a little better now, thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Well, your code has a lot of problems. But answer to your questions is simple:

You create a bunch of threads in 2 `for` loops, but there is no points of synchronization\ communication between threads, so they act independently in the meaning that when you call `start` method of a `Thread` instance it will execute `run` method, well, in separate thread. There is nothing in you program that prevents threads if 2nd loop to be created only after threads from 1st loop finish their execution. So there are no extra threads created here. You just solve your solution in a wrong way.